# fix sql query (work before update mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

what is the error in current query? (it's working before update mysql)

receive:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE ON LIKE.feed_item_id = feed_item.id AND LIKE.user_id= LEFT JOIN category ON' at line 15
```

query:

```
SELECT feed_item.*,
       user.id AS user_id,
       user.first_name,
       user.last_name,
       user.avatar_url,
       category.name AS category_name,
       feed_item.*,
       user.id AS user_id,
       user.first_name,
       user.last_name,
       user.avatar_url,
       like.user_id AS is_liked
FROM (feed_item)
LEFT JOIN USER ON USER.id=feed_item.user_id
LEFT JOIN LIKE ON LIKE.feed_item_id = feed_item.id
AND LIKE.user_id=
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id=feed_item.category_id
WHERE feed_item.visibility IN ('public')
  AND feed_item.user_id != 0
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 11
```

how to fix this?
thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIKE` is a reserved keyword, you need to wrap it in backticks, also here `LIKE.user_id=` you haven't specified a parameter for the equality condition (eg `LIKE.user_id = 30`)

```
SELECT feed_item.*,
   user.id AS user_id,
   user.first_name,
   user.last_name,
   user.avatar_url,
   category.name AS category_name,
   feed_item.*,
   user.id AS user_id,
   user.first_name,
   user.last_name,
   user.avatar_url,
   `like`.user_id AS is_liked
FROM feed_item
LEFT JOIN USER ON USER.id=feed_item.user_id
LEFT JOIN `LIKE` ON `LIKE`.`feed_item_id` = feed_item.id
AND `LIKE`.`user_id`= feed_item.user_id // <- here
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id=feed_item.category_id
WHERE feed_item.visibility IN ('public')
  AND feed_item.user_id != 0
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 11
```

Comment: Even with the backticks?

Answer (score 1):

'LIKE' is a reserved keyword in SQL, so I would strongly suggest not naming a table that. I imagine that is what is causing your error!

Answer (score 1):

If you can rename your table, do it. 'Like' is a keyword for SQL, so use it like that generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your table name; `LIKE` and `USER` are reserved words. Try to include a prefix like `tbl_like` or make it plural ("likes").

```
SELECT users.id AS user_id,
       users.first_name,
       users.last_name,
       users.avatar_url,
       category.name AS category_name,
       users.id AS user_id,
       users.first_name,
       users.last_name,
       users.avatar_url,
       likes.user_id AS is_liked
FROM feed_item
LEFT JOIN USERs ON USERs.id=feed_item.user_id
LEFT JOIN LIKEs ON LIKEs.feed_item_id = feed_item.id
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id=feed_item.category_id
WHERE feed_item.visibility IN ('public')
  AND feed_item.user_id != 0
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 11
```